# Regex hyphen causing issues

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to use python to extract invoice info from a text file. The items always start with a quantity (1 x, 2 x, etc) and end with a part number, for various reasons the descriptions can differ even for the same item. The following regex seems to pull out most of the entries, but fails when there is a hyphen '-' in the description.

**Regex:**

```
^([0-9]+\sx) [\w\s\r\n®.,]* [0-9]{3}-\d[A-Z]\d+(-AB)?
```

I'm struggling to work out how to modify the regex to deal with this. I though adding *(\s-\s)* in would help, but the regex then seems to match parts of different entries rather than the individual ones. I'm sure there are more efficient ways of writing the regex, but I don't use them that often, so getting this far was an achievement. Any pointers gratefully received.

Example entries shown below. With the above regex, the middle one doesn't get matched unless I delete the '-'

```
1 x Product® 100, Low range items

3,456.00 USD

Cat. No. 012-3A45


1 x Product® 100. Low range items - LRI

123,456.00 USD

Part. no. 201-5G95


2 x Product Mid Range Items

7,654.00 USD

Art. no. 001-8Q147-AB
```

Comment: Try putting a hyphen inside the part that is supposed to match the description:  `[-\w\s\r\n®.,]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hyphen and make the pattern non greedy

```
^([0-9]+\sx) [-\w\s®.,]*? [0-9]{3}-\d[A-Z]\d+(-AB)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7XuX6W/1)

Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

Comment: Doing that returns all three sets of info as a single match rather than 3 separate matches, that why I'd ended up thinking the \s-\s approach would be better. And if there's other text between the entries that also gets included in the match.

Comment: @CodgerCoder Did you check the regex demo? The result for your example data is 3 matches.

Comment: yep, i stuffed up when putting it into the rest of the script - my snafu. Thanks.